# Highcharts Timeline with xAxis values

Tags: highcharts

I need to create a chart with fixed values xaxis although it contains no data to graph like this: 
[Is importante the min value for yaxis must be (0) but show 1 grid line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMdTc.jpg)
(The color does not matter, and I need to show minute by minute interval, eg 18:50, 18:51, 18: 52, 18:53 ... 10 Total ticks)

as it should be the format xaxis?

as it should enter data values?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), please check this link about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use showEmpty parameter of your xAxis and yAxis to show them without any data. You can also add min and max values for calculating the extremes of your axes.

If you want to have an interval of your ticks equal to 1 min you can set it using tickInterval: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Here you can find code that may help you:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: Date.UTC(2016, 01, 01, 01),
      showEmpty: true,
      max: Date.UTC(2016, 01, 01, 01, 30),
      tickInterval: 1000 * 60, // one minute
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      showEmpty: true
    },
    series: [{

    }]
});
```

And here you can find live example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/wys1duhq/1/

Comment: ...and how to set xaxis to 10 ticks and values fix?

Comment: The simplest way of setting your axis ticks to fixed values is to use tickPositions or tickPositioner. You can find information about these parameters here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner